# Python: Where is freeze.py?

Tags: python

Anyone know where freeze.py is installed for 2.6.5? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Did it get pulled out and replaced with something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's where it's always been, under `Tools/` in the source distribution.

Comment: I didn't have the sources installed. Thanks

Comment: And if you don't have a Tools folder: `apt-get install python2.7-examples` http://askubuntu.com/questions/282824/where-can-i-find-the-python-tools-directory

Answer (score 2):

use in linux command `locate freeze.py`

```
root@root:/usr/lib/python2.7$ locate freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.pyc
/usr/share/king-phisher/tools/cx_freeze.py
```

Comment: For what it's worth, these are the freeze.py for `pip freeze`, and not the tool to freeze a Python script into a binary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the error: "needed directory /usr/local/lib/python/lib not found"?

You need to configure Freeze before you use it. Run "make libainstall" in your Python build tree.

Answer (score -3):

It took me a while to figure it out: you need package "python-pip" (with dependencies) to be installed. I also got myself "python-tools" installed but that was no help.

```
root ~ #> locate freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
```

Comment: Unless this is snark (it very well could be?) this is not the `freeze.py` the OP is looking for :)