# What can be (safely) removed from custom python installation on linux, to make it smaller

Tags: python, linux, compilation

For one of my projects at work I needed to create a standalone python installation (from source). However, the complete directory takes ~90MB of disk space, not much, but too much to be replicated over and over.

**Which files can I remove from the custom python installation directory?**

There is a large "test" folder (./lib/python2.7/test), everything is precompiled (but 99% of modules will not be used in this project), libpython2.7.a is placed twice (./lib and .lib/python2.7/config), etc.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

Comment: Get the embeddable distribution.

Answer (score 2):

`freeze.py` should help you - it's part of the standard installation.

See: [Python: Where is freeze.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016855/python-where-is-freeze-py)

and: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

and the README: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/freeze/README

It tries to only include what is required.

Comment: Hm..., freezing seems going a bit too far, but I will try what I can get with it, thanks!