# Python Freeze Not Returning/Doing Anything

Tags: python

I am trying to run Freeze. I am running on CentOS with base python2.4, but have python2.7.

My freeze.py is in : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/freeze.py`. It is under python2.7.

When running `python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/freeze.py myapp.py`, I get nothing back.

Why is this happening? Does anyone have any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `freeze.py` file is used for the `pip freeze` command, which is used to:

```
Output all currently installed packages (exact versions) to stdout
```

I guess you want to build a standalone binary with [Freeze](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze), see: [Python: Where is freeze.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016855/python-where-is-freeze-py)