# Freezing a Python application on Travis CI

Tags: python, c, makefile, rake, travis-ci

I am trying to freeze a Python application within Travis CI via a Github project. I manage to successfully invoke the installation of the `freeze.py` utility via `pip` within Travis, but when I attempt to freeze the Python program it runs but does not generate the necessary C and Makefile needed to build an executable.

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python:
   - "2.7"

# Command to install dependencies
install: "pip install freeze"

# Command to build with `rake`
script: rake default
```

And this is my Rakefile:

```
#
# Rakefile to build standalone `secho` Unix-like executable program on Travis CI.
# To build on your own system; please use `make` instead.
#
freeze = "python /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-           packages/pip/commands/freeze.py"
io = "secho"

task :default => [:freeze, :compile]

task :freeze do
  sh "python #{io}.py python test output - OK"
  sh "#{freeze} #{io}.py" # This runs but there is no console output & nothing generated.
end

task :compile do
  sh "ls"
  sh "make -f Makefile"
  sh "strip #{io}"
  sh "rm -f Makefile *.o *.c"
  sh "./#{io} compiled test output - OK"
end

task :clean do
  sh "rm -f #{io}"
end

task :test do
  puts "dummy test"
end
```

Only running the script with Python in the first task `:freeze` seems to complete successfully. What have I done wrong?

Many thanks,

Sam.

https://github.com/stpettersens/super-echo

Comment: I'm a little confused.  The `freeze` package you're installing with pip as a dependency has nothing to do with the "pip freeze" command.  The `pip.commands.freeze` module is not runnable as a script like you're trying to do.  To run `pip freeze` just run `sh "pip freeze"`.  But I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what happened here.  Perhaps you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016855/python-where-is-freeze-py) which had an answer suggesting that `freeze.py` lives in a module in pip, and is not even directly runnable as a script (you can confirm this by reading its source code which just contains little more than a class definition).

But I think what you're looking for is the `freeze.py` tool that ships with Python's source code.  This is, as far as I know, not normally installed and is just a tool included in the source: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5f5e1d408c0c/Tools/freeze

If you're looking for a tool to freeze your script as a stand-alone executable you might want to look into something like [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) or [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).  The freeze utility included in Python isn't really maintained or used anymore, I don't think. Except maybe for recent work to keep it Python 3 compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just wanted to run the `freeze.py` utility to generated the necessary C code and `Makefile` to that I can invoke the compiler on. Can I install `cx_Freeze` via `pip` and then run that? That would work too.

Comment: That sort of depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but `cx_Freeze` for example doesn't output a C file or a Makefile--it just outputs a binary executable rather than requiring you to compile it.  It also (by default) produces a .zip file containing all your Python modules, though the specifics can be tweaked.  Take a look at the docs and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Just want the executable, so what I want. Thanks. Can I install it under Travis though?

Comment: Should be able--`pip install cx_Freeze` should work, in principle.

Comment: Go ahead and read the docs and give it a try a few times--I would recommend trying to get it working locally, if you can, before fussing with trying to get it work in Travis.  There are many guides to bundling Python scripts as executables, and many questions related to it on SO.  But as it stands the answer you your specific question is that you were trying to run a Python module that is not executable, and that has nothing to do with what you're trying to accomplish :)